# How to make Foundation Apps Interchange load images as needed?

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-apps

The [documentation](http://base-apps.github.io/angular-base-apps/latest/#!/interchange) for the Foundation for Apps (and Angular Base Apps, which is the now-maintained fork of F4A) Interchange gives this example as a way to load only the small size of an image on mobile devices in order to save bandwidth:

```
<ba-interchange>
    <img media="small" src="assets/img/small.jpg">
    <img media="medium" src="assets/img/medium.jpg">
    <img media="large" src="assets/img/large.jpg">
</ba-interchange>
```

However, while only the small image is displayed, the browser still sees three `img` tags and requests all three images, before angular is even loaded. This defeats the purpose of using the interchange at all, at least, if your purpose is to save bandwidth.

The Foundation 6 for Sites Interchange avoids this by putting all of the images into a `data-interchange` attribute string on the element instead. Does F4A have something similar that I'm missing? Or is there something about the above example code that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `ba-if` directive provided by Angular Base Apps.  This directive internally uses the `ng-if` directive, causing the `img` element to not be added to the DOM except when the specified media query is matched.

Your code can be re-written as follows using the `ba-if` directive:

```
<img ba-if="small only" src="assets/img/small.jpg">
<img ba-if="medium only" src="assets/img/medium.jpg">
<img ba-if="large only" src="assets/img/large.jpg">
```

Comment: Isn't this basically the same thing ba-interchange does? I tried it, but I still see all three images being fetched, because the browser sees the img tags before angular is loaded.

Comment: ba-if uses [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) under the hood, which doesn't render the DOM if the expression is false

Comment: Right, but this only works if Angular is loading the template. In my case the template is part of the initial request. The browser is rendering the img tags before Angular is even loaded.

However what does work is to use ng-src instead of src, to give control of the img loading to Angular.